# jQuery doesn't work with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm learning MVC and I am trying to use jQuery. This is my code:

_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript">    
    </script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"  type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>   
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>

<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/JScript1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<h2 id="ind">Index</h2>

<div id="picture">

</div>
```

and JScript1.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("Test alert");
    $("#picture div").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Alert shows fine but color doesn't change. Nothing with jQuery doesn't work. I have also tried:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

but this also doesn't work.

What's the problem here it should be very simple???

Comment: This selector is invalid: `$("#picture div")`. There's no `div` element contained in an element with id `picture` in your page.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ refer this for jquery...

Comment: have you included all the css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used

```
<div id="picture">
  TEST
</div>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  alert("Test alert");
  $("#picture").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Without something in the div it doesn't show. also here could be something in Site.css that is messing with this

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("Test alert");
    $("div #picture").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

In your code, you use: `#picture div`, and the script tries to set color to `div` which is NESTED in the element with id = `picture`. You should use `$("div #picture")`, or even shorter (as each id has to be unique) : `$("#picture")`.

Comment: I have tried that and added in div <h1>Testing</h1> but it only shows Testing and color doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("Test alert");
    $("div#picture").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Or better to use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        alert("Test alert");
        $("#picture").css("background-color", "red");
    });
```

Comment: `$("div #picture")` it returns nothing. Are you telling `$("div#picture")`? Then edit your code